# How to read a file in node js?

Tags: node.js, fs, readfile

When i want to read a file in node js it won't display the file in the browser when I execute.
and in the terminal says no such file or directory while I use the exact file path anyone can answer this why?

Here is the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const CORS = require('cors');
let port = 3000;
app.use(CORS());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

app.use(express.static('Docs'));


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    
    res.json({name: 'waris', favFood: 'Pizza'})

    fs.readFile('./docs/index.html', (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            res.send(data);
        }
    })
    
    
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Running on port ${port}`);
})
```

Comment: You try to send two responses, the first on is `res.json` and the second one is `res.send`. Remove `res.json`.

Comment: Try to resolve the path to an absolute path on the filesystem, i.e `path.resolve(__dirname, './relative/path/to/file/from/script')`. You'll need `const path = require('path')` too.